# Wicket setResponsePage calls constructor multiple times

Tags: java, wicket

Trying to pass a model from one page to another.
Application.init
`getRequestCycleSettings().setRenderStrategy(RequestCycleSettings.RenderStrategy.ONE_PASS_RENDER)`

I have two pages, both defined with 3 constructors each. PageOne has a form. OnSubmit is supposed to pass the page model from PageOne to PageTwo.

The call to setResponsePage first calls the constructor WebPage​(IModel<?> model) and passes the model, as expected.

But immediately after that, it also calls the WebPage​() (noargs) *and* the WebPage​(PageParameters parameters) constructor.
As a result, PageTwo gets constructed 3 times and ends up having a null DefaultModel.

How can i tell Wicket to stop after calling the WebPage​(IModel<?> model) contructor?

Here is the code:

```
public class PageOne extends WebPage {
    // Similar constructors for PageTwo
    public PageOne() {
        super();
    }

    public PageOne(PageParameters p) {
        super(p);
    }

    public PageOne(IModel<?> model) {
        super(model);
    }

   @Override
   protected void onInitialize() {
       super.onInitialize();

       Form<Void> form = new Form<Void>("form") {
           @Override
           public void onSubmit() {
               setResponsePage(new PageTwo((IModel<?>)getDefaultModel()));
           }
      };
   }
}
```

Thank you

Wicket version is 9.13.0

Application is a Springboot App (springboot version 2.7.11), in case that matters.

I expect setresponsePage to call the right constructor only once and pass the model.

Answer (score 0):

```
I expect setresponsePage to call the right constructor only once and pass the model.
```

Me too! But I need to debug it to see why this happens.

You could try with:

```
@Override
public void onSubmit() {
    throw new RestartResponseException(new PageTwo((IModel<?>)getDefaultModel()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply
Adding RestartResponseException does not change anything

Tha call stack is different between the first (correct) call and the following 2 calls to the noargs and the PageParameters constructor. In the first call stack i see my own component and the onSubmit() call. In the other 2 call stacks there is no class of mine included. Everything comes from wicket libs.

i'd attach both screenshots with the different call stacks, but i do not know how to attach files in SO.

Thanks again